# Ways to avoid Iterator ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, iterator

As far as I know there are two ways to avoid ConcurrentModificationException while one threading iterates the collection and another thread modifies the collection.

1. client-locking, basically lock the collection during the iteration. Other threads that need to access the collection will block until the iteration is complete.
2. "thread-confined" that clones the collection and iterate the copy.

I am wondering are there any other alternatives ? 
because the first way obvious is undesirable and poor performance-wise, if the collection is large that other threads could wait for a long time. second way I am not sure that since we clone the collection, and iterate the copy, so if other threads come in and modify the original one, then the copied one becomes stale right ?  does that mean we need to restart over by cloning and iterate it again once it's modified ?

Comment: There is third way also use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) if you are writes are less than reads.

Comment: @AmitD can you explain more about it please...why writes less than reads ? does it work just like concurrentHashMap ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am wondering are there any other alternatives ?

Use one of the concurrent collections which doesn't throw this exception.  Instead they provide weak consistency. i.e. an added or delete element may or may not appear while iterating.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

> The java.util.concurrent package includes a number of additions to the Java Collections Framework. These are most easily categorized by the collection interfaces provided:
>
> - BlockingQueue defines a first-in-first-out data structure that blocks or times out when you attempt to add to a full queue, or retrieve from an empty queue.
> - ConcurrentMap is a subinterface of java.util.Map that defines useful atomic operations. These operations remove or replace a key-value pair only if the key is present, or add a key-value pair only if the key is absent. Making these operations atomic helps avoid synchronization. The standard general-purpose implementation of ConcurrentMap is ConcurrentHashMap, which is a concurrent analog of HashMap.
> - ConcurrentNavigableMap is a subinterface of ConcurrentMap that supports approximate matches. The standard general-purpose implementation of ConcurrentNavigableMap is ConcurrentSkipListMap, which is a concurrent analog of TreeMap.

Comment: I am wondering which one is most widely and prefer to use in practice ? out of the 2 above and concurrent package collections ?

Comment: @user1389813 The one which suits your needs is the one to use.  They are not interchangeable. In your cause you might want CopyOnWriteArraList, CopyOnWriteArraySet, ConcurrentLinkedDeque or one of the many other concurrent collections.

Comment: you said "an added or deleted element may or may not appear while iterating", so how do we know if it's appeared or not ?

Comment: If you see it while iterating, it appeared. If you don't see it while iterating, it didn't appear.

Comment: I mean how do we know if the operations has effected to the iteration ?

Comment: It is assumed you don't need to know if there is another thread which is iterating which may or may not see the change you made.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Class's from [java.util.Concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) like [**CopyOnWriteArrayList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)